# SQL CASE statement returns duplicate values

Tags: sql, case, amazon-redshift

Here is how my data looks

```
title  value 
------------
 t1      v1
 t2      v2
 t3      v3
```

Now I want `t1` and `t2` to be inferred as the same value `t12`. So, I do:

```
SELECT 
    CASE
       WHEN title = 't1' OR title = 't2' 
          THEN 't12'
          ELSE title 
    END AS inferred_title,
    COUNT(value)
FROM 
    my_table
GROUP BY 
    inferred_title;
```

I expected the output to be:

```
inferred title  values
-----------------------
   t12            2
   t3             1
```

But what I end up getting is:

```
inferred title     values
--------------------------
   t12                1
   t12                1
   t3                 1
```

How do I make it behave the way I want it to? I don't want the duplicated rows.

Comment: What's your DBMS? it brings results as you want for Postgresql and MySQL 8.

Comment: Group by can't use the alias, due to order of operation.  Group by must have the case statement as well; or you must use a subquery/cte to get the result of the case and it's alias prior to aggregation..  Only the order by can uses the alias

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Redshift, so Postgresql

Comment: your case works on Postgresql even in [ver. 8.4](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=da122f79ef1fbdb1d19272a56da5dc0e) , but I cannot say anything for Red-shift, seems it doesn't

Comment: @Barbaros i know that using expression alias in group by doesnt work. But what o/p it is showing as 1 what count it is as if it doesnt work why it din gave error to OP

Comment: No @HimanshuAhuja , I meant expression alias in group by works in Postgresql (even as intended giving the results for count as 2,1). Meanwhile I cannot say anything related to Redshift, since have no medium to be installed for that DBMS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is scoping.  You must have an `inferred_title` in the table.  Either give a new column alias or repeat the expression:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN title IN ('t1', 't2') THEN 't12'
             ELSE title
        END) AS inferred_title,
       COUNT(value)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN title IN ('t1', 't2') THEN 't12'
               ELSE title
          END);
```

Comment: i know that using expression alias in group by doesnt work. But what o/p it is showing as 1 what count it is as if it doesnt work why it din gave error to OP

Answer (score 1):

Do the "merge" `case` in a derived table (sub-query), `group by` its result:

```
SELECT inferred_title, COUNT(value)
FROM
(
    SELECT CASE WHEN title = 't1' OR title = 't2' THEN 't12'
                ELSE title 
           END AS inferred_title,
           value
    FROM my_table
) dt
GROUP BY inferred_title;
```

This saves you some typing, is less error prone and easier to maintain - and is 
ANSI SQL compliant!

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Title, COUNT(Title) AS Totals
From my_table          
Group By Title
Having COUNT(Title)>1
Order By 2 desc
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing on StackO. Strive to always add some explanation in your answers to help understand how it addresses the question, what is missing or needs to be changed in the provided code (if any) instead of just putting some bare code.

Comment: BTW this answer does NOT address the question as you are keeping the original `title` value when the OP would like to build a different title depending on the original `title` value